# Rails - Elastick Beanstalk nginx/error.log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Trying to upload my rails app to elastic beanstalk. I have successfully deployed my app and created postgres database. My app works on sqlite3 on development server.

my eb status is ready and health is green.

my eb logs file;

```
/var/log/nginx/error.log
-------------------------------------
2016/05/27 11:15:44 [warn] 2797#0: conflicting server name "localhost" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2016/05/27 11:27:26 [crit] 2805#0: *140 connect() to unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.26.77, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock:/", host: "viravira-env.bu2eqpbwny.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com"
2016/05/27 11:27:26 [crit] 2805#0: *140 connect() to unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.26.77, server: _, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock:/favicon.ico", host: "viravira-env.bu2eqpbwny.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com", referrer: "http://viravira-env.bu2eqpbwny.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/"
2016/05/27 11:34:45 [crit] 2805#0: *262 connect() to unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.46.145, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock:/", host: "viravira-env.bu2eqpbwny.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com"
2016/05/27 11:34:45 [crit] 2805#0: *262 connect() to unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.46.145, server: _, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock:/favicon.ico", host: "viravira-env.bu2eqpbwny.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com", referrer: "http://viravira-env.bu2eqpbwny.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/"
2016/05/27 11:40:48 [crit] 2805#0: *353 connect() to unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.46.145, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock:/", host: "viravira-env.bu2eqpbwny.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com"
2016/05/27 11:40:49 [crit] 2805#0: *353 connect() to unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.46.145, server: _, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock:/favicon.ico", host: "viravira-env.bu2eqpbwny.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com", referrer: "http://viravira-env.bu2eqpbwny.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/"



-------------------------------------
/var/log/puma/puma.log
-------------------------------------
=== puma startup: 2016-05-27 11:52:07 +0000 ===
=== puma startup: 2016-05-27 11:52:07 +0000 ===
[23871] - Worker 0 (pid: 23875) booted, phase: 0
[23871] - Gracefully shutting down workers...
[23871] === puma shutdown: 2016-05-27 12:36:32 +0000 ===
[23871] - Goodbye!
=== puma startup: 2016-05-27 12:36:35 +0000 ===
=== puma startup: 2016-05-27 12:36:35 +0000 ===
[24886] - Worker 0 (pid: 24890) booted, phase: 0
```

I am fairly new to eb so I wonder if the problem occurs because of the followings;

1. I have not installed node that is why it can not connect
2. Or I have problems with the security groups. I have 4 total as seen in the picture.
   [image]

my network interfaces;
[image]
when I try to detach RDS security group, it gives an error no authorization, even though I signed in as root. 
[image]
I have been trying to solve the problem for hours now and really appreciate any help!

**EDIT**
I think I m having same issue as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22272943/nginx-cannot-find-unix-socket-file-with-unicorn-no-such-file-or-directory). But could not understand how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is very clear from the Nginx log:

> connect() to unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream

It reads:

**No such file or directory**

This means that your socket doesn't not exist at this path:

`/var/run/puma/my_app.sock`

1. You need to setup the path to be the same as in your Rails/Puma
   upstream(i.e. configuration)
2. When you will do that **don't forget** to make sure that Nginx user
   can access that socket it will need **RW** access.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I am kind of newbie on elastic beanstalk and i would really appreciate if you can guide me step by step

Comment: Have you tried to create the socket? Is Nginx working now ?

Comment: I did not figure out how i can create the socket and setup the path